# logstash can't find jdk

Tags: java, logstash

I want to start using logstash and elastic search. I followd the documentation from elastic

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html

and I want to start with this first demo command.I work on windows 10 64 bit. So I downloaded the logstash.zip, opened the cmd and moved to the

> C:\Program Files\Logstash\logstash-6.3.1\bin>

folder. After that I entered

> logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'

and then I got an error that

> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
>   can't be found or loaded. (Sorry I develop in german and I don't know the english error message)

I run eclipse and Java on this pc and the command

> javac

shows

```
> Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -parameters                Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -h <directory>             Specify where to place generated native header files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -profile <profile>         Check that API used is available in the specified profile
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  -Werror                    Terminate compilation if warnings occur
  @<filename>                Read options and filenames from file
```

and

> java -version

outputs

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

so I guess this should be fine.
Can anyone help me why logstash can't find it? Do I have to set some extra stuff?
In Systemvariables I set jdk and jre to the "Path" Variable and I made a JAVA_HOME variable in Users Variables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin can't be found or loaded." The path is missing the prefix - "C:\Program ". Is it just a copy/paste mistake, or is that how it's in the actual error?

Comment: this is the error statement:
Error: Main class Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program could not be found or loaded

Comment: "Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin" looks like an incomplete path. As "javac" and "java" are working for you - what is logstash? A script? An executable? Maybe something is mixed up there. If possible, could you add the relevant environment variables to your question.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file. unpacked it and that's it. Documentation says nothing more

Comment: You could try moving your logstash installation to something like `C:\Logstash\logstash-6.3.1\bin>`, so you have path with no space.

Comment: I moved the installation but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your JAVA_HOME and PATH is messed up. It has to be something like this

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 
PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

To cross check you can try this in terminal

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

and

```
javac -version
```

to check class PATH variable.

You can refer [this link](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10) for step to step process to set variables.

Comment: echo %JAVA_HOME%
returns C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

javac -version does not work. only java -version and it says
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: javac -version should also work..  Can you check if you hace set PATH variable correctly. As PATH variables contains multiple entry seperated by semicolon.  Refer this   https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10

Comment: Thank's for the link. I followed the instruction and now both work. javac -version outputs javac 1.8.0_144 and echo outputs C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144 but logstash still shows the same error